# Continuity a function of several real variables

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, multivariable-calculus, continuity

The goal is to study the continuity of the following function:

$f(x, y)= \begin{cases}x^{2}y, & \text { si }|x|<y \\ y, & \text { otherwise. }\end{cases}$

$D_{f}=\left\{(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^{2}:|x|<y\right\} \cup\left\{(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^{2}:|x| \geq y\right\}=\mathbb{R}^{2} .$

**My attempt**

We set  $D_{1}=\left\{(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^{2}:|x|<y\right\} ; D_{2}=\left\{(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^{2}:|x|>y\right\} ; D_{3}=\left\{(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^{2}:|x|=y\right\}$.

- On $D_{1}, f$ is continuous Polynomial function.
- On $D_{2}, f$ is continuous Polynomial function.

Answer (score 1):

The function will be continuous on $(0,0),$ $(-1,1)$ and $(1,1),$ as well as $D_1$ and $D_2,$ but nowhere else.

The rough idea on $|x| = y = 1$ is as follows: consider a small change $(h,k) \approx (0,0),$ then $(1+h)^2(1+k) - 1 = 2h+h^2 = (2+h) h + (1+h)^2k$ and the absolute value of this will be $< \varepsilon$ if $\|(h,k)\| < \varepsilon/7$ (assuming $\varepsilon < 1$ ahd then $|2+h| \leq 3$ and $|1+h|^2 \leq 4$), on the other hand, $1+k-1 = k,$ which implies that $|f(1+h,1+k)-f(1,1)| \leq \max(|(2+h)h + (1+h)^2k|, |k|) < \varepsilon.$

When $x = y = 0,$ we will reach $f(0,0) = 0$ and $|f(h,k)| \leq \max(h^2|k|, |k|) \to 0.$

For other $(x,y)$ with $|x| = y \neq 0,$ note that
$$
|x^2 (y + k) - y| = |x^2 k + (x^2-1) y| \geq (x^2-1)|y| - x^2 |k| > (x^2-1)|y|/2 > 0
$$ provided $k > 0$ is small enough. So, $f(x, y +k) \not\to f(x,y)$ which shows discontinuity.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is correct. In general, $f$ is not continuous on $D_3$. Fix $(x,|x|)\in D_3$, define sequence $(x_n,y_n)=(x,|x|-\frac{1}{n})\in D_1$. Then $f(x_n,y_n)=x^2(|x|-\frac{1}{n})\to x^2|x|$ as $n\to\infty$ and $(x_n,y_n)\to (x,|x|)$ as $n\to\infty$. But $f(x,|x|)=|x|$, which is in general not equal to $x^2|x|$. This leaves a question - what if $x^2|x|=|x|$? That gives three cases you can figure out using epsilon-delta definition.